# How to find time spent (engagement_time) on our app by the users in BigQuery?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I am trying to calculate the total time spent by users on my app. We have integrated firebase analytics data in BigQuery. Can I use the sum of the values of engagement_time_msec/1000 in the select statement of my query? This is what I am trying :

`SELECT SUM(x.value.int_value) FROM "[dataset]", UNNEST(event_params) AS x WHERE x.key = "engagement_time_msec"`

I am getting very big values after executing this query(it giving huge hours per day). I am not sure if is it ok to use SUM("engagement_time_msec") for calculating the total time spent by users on the app.

I am not expecting that users are spending this much time on the app. Is it the right way to calculate engagement_time, or which is the best event to calculate the engagement_time?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to accomplish using your data would help.

Answer (score 1):

As per [google analytics docs](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7061705?hl=en-419) in regards to `engagement_time_sec`, this field is defined as "The additional engagement time (ms) since the last user_engagement event". Therefore, if you only look at this, you are losing all the previous time spent by users before the mentioned `user_engagement` event is triggered.

What I'd do, since now `ga_session_id` is defined, would be to grab the maximum and minimum for each `ga_session_id` timestamp, use the `TIMESTAMP_DIFF()` function for each case, and sum the results of all the sessions for a given day:

```
WITH ga_sessions AS (
  SELECT
    event_timestamp,
    event_date,
    params.value.int_value AS ga_session_id
  FROM 
    `analytics_123456789.events_*`, UNNEST(event_params) AS params
  WHERE 
    params.key = "ga_session_id"
),
session_length AS (
  SELECT
    event_date,
    TIMESTAMP_DIFF(MAX(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)), MIN(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)), SECOND) AS session_duration_seconds
  FROM
    ga_sessions
  WHERE 
    ga_session_id IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY
    1
),
final AS (
  SELECT 
    event_date,
    SUM(session_duration_seconds) as total_seconds_in_app
  FROM 
    session_length 
  GROUP BY
    1
  ORDER BY
    1 DESC
)
SELECT * FROM final
```

**OUTPUT** (data extracted from the app I work at):

```
event_date | total_seconds_in_app
-----------+--------------------
20210920   | 45600
20210919   | 43576
20210918   | 44539
```